# How to use Android tesseract Android.mk files in my Android.mk?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android.mk

I was digging on using `android tesseract api` in my project.

https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

I copied **com_googlecode_leptonica_android** and **com_googlecode_tesseract_android** directory from **tess-two** to my project **jni directory**, my **jni folder structure**:

```
Android.mk
Application.mk
com_googlecode_leptonica_android
com_googlecode_tesseract_android
main_jni.cpp
...other h and cpp files...
```

I'm not sure how to include the **Android.mk files** in **com_googlecode_leptonica_android** and **com_googlecode_tesseract_android** inside my **Android.mk** file in **jni directory**.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TESSERACT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src
LEPTONICA_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/src
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
$(info $(NDK_MODULE_PATH))
LOCAL_CFLAGS :=  -Wno-psabi
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android_native_app_glue
FILE_LIST_CPP := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp) # finds all cpp files
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST_CPP:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += \
    -DDEBUG \
    -DDEFAULT_DIR=\"/default\"
LOCAL_MODULE    := MyModule

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

which does not work.

How to get this work?

Comment: Why not build using the regular build [instructions](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#build) and import as a library project as suggested?

Comment: I wanted to use my existing project and jni, and want to include tesseract libraries there. I'm using tesseract modules in my jni and not sure how to include them in Android.mk

Comment: @rmtheis Can I export the tess-two project to jar file and use that in my project?

Comment: I don't think it will work as a jar.

Comment: @rmtheis How can I use tesseract methods in jni method?

Comment: An example: [https://github.com/…](https://github.com/renard314/textfairy/blob/master/textfairy/jni/ocr/ocr.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't compile Android.mk files in tess-two project, I just ended up with importing **libtess.so** and **liblept.so** files into my Android.mk as prebuilt library and I could use tesseract libraries in my jni file.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you did this?