# Adding Tesseract and Opencv to Android.mk (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, tesseract, android.mk

I followed the instructions from [here](http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2014/10/22/android-ndk-and-opencv-development-with-android-studio/) and added OpenCV successfully. But I've been trying to add tesseract to the Android.mk as well, for a few days now, and haven't been able to do it.

I have an *android.cpp* that uses tesseract so I have to include the dependency in my Android.mk . I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965907/how-to-use-android-tesseract-android-mk-files-in-my-android-mk) that had almost the exact problem and he solved it importing *libtess.so* and *liblept.so* files into Android.mk, but didn't explain how to do that, so I looked and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870435/how-can-i-link-prebuilt-shared-library-to-android-ndk-project/9922835#9922835) that shows how to link prebuilt libraries. So based on that I tried this Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := liblept
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/liblept.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../tess-two/jni
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtess
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libtess.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../tess-two/jni
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_PACKAGE_DIR:= /Users/danielsierraf/Documents/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := off
include $(OPENCV_PACKAGE_DIR)/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := run_detection
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtess
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := text_detect.cpp android.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And got this output:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : liblept.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : liblept.so => src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/liblept.so
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: run_detection <= text_detect.cpp
In file included from src/main/jni/text_detect.h:4:0,
                 from src/main/jni/text_detect.cpp:10:
src/main/jni/../../../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/api/baseapi.h:32:22: fatal error: platform.h: No such file or directory
 #include "platform.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

So I guess is not linking libtess correctly, and if you look closely, it doesn't ever install libtess.so, it looks like it installs *liblept.so*, and then jumps to *text_detect.cpp*, ignoring this part:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtess
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libtess.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../tess-two/jni
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

So I tried to force it to install *liblept* and *libtess* completely before proceeding by putting it in different files. So I put the last part of the file in a different Android.mk in another folder and tried *include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)*,  and then it installs *libtess* and *liblept* completely, but ignores the *call all-subdir-makefiles*.

new jni folder structure:

```
Android.mk
Application.mk
text_detect/
     Android.mk
     android.cpp
     text_detect.cpp
     text_detect.h
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := liblept
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/liblept.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../tess-two/jni
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libtess
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libtess.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../tess-two/jni
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

textdetect/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_PACKAGE_DIR:= /Users/danielsierraf/Documents/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := off
include $(OPENCV_PACKAGE_DIR)/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := run_detection
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtess
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := text_detect.cpp android.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And this is the output:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : liblept.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : liblept.so => src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/liblept.so
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libtess.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libtess.so => src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libtess.so
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : liblept.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/armeabi/
[armeabi] Install        : liblept.so => src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/liblept.so
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : libtess.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/armeabi/
[armeabi] Install        : libtess.so => src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libtess.so
[mips] Prebuilt       : liblept.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/mips/
[mips] Install        : liblept.so => src/main/jniLibs/mips/liblept.so
[mips] Prebuilt       : libtess.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/mips/
[mips] Install        : libtess.so => src/main/jniLibs/mips/libtess.so
[x86] Prebuilt       : liblept.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/x86/
[x86] Install        : liblept.so => src/main/jniLibs/x86/liblept.so
[x86] Prebuilt       : libtess.so <= src/main/jni/../libs/x86/
[x86] Install        : libtess.so => src/main/jniLibs/x86/libtess.so
```

As you see it installs everything from the first Android.mk perfectly, but it never runs textdetect/Android.mk

So, what I'm I doing wrong? How can I achieve this task that seems so simple? Is there an easier way?

**EDIT:**

After @ph0b response I went back to my first setup and added the same `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` as the [original Makefiles](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/Android.mk#L33) (with a couple of variations adapting it to my paths), and that solved it. It couldn't find `platform.h` because it didn't know where to look for it.

Now, after I did this change I had a different error `No such file or directory #include "com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/api/baseapi.h"` and I thought this was because it didn't compile tesseract before `run_detection` that depends on it. Well that wasn't the problem, it still compiles `run_detection` before tesseract but that wasn't the issue, it was so much simpler and I feel so stupid for having spent so much time on this error. The problem was it didn't find `com_googlecode_tesseract_android/src/api/baseapi.h` because I didn't provide the path for that either, so I copied `com_googlecode_tesseract_android` and `com_googlecode_leptonica_android` from [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/tree/master/tess-two/jni) and added `$(LOCAL_PATH)` to `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES`. This is my final solution:

jni folder structure:

```
Android.mk
Application.mk
text_detect.cpp
android.cpp
text_detect.h
com_googlecode_leptonica_android
com_googlecode_tesseract_android
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#leptonica
LEPTONICA_LOCAL := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_leptonica_android
LEPTONICA_PATH := $(LEPTONICA_LOCAL)/src

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := liblept
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/liblept.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := \
  $(LEPTONICA_LOCAL) \
  $(LEPTONICA_PATH)/src

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#tesseract
TESSERACT_LOCAL := $(LOCAL_PATH)/com_googlecode_tesseract_android
TESSERACT_PATH := $(TESSERACT_LOCAL)/src

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libtess
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libtess.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := \
  $(LOCAL_PATH) \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/api \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/ccmain \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/ccstruct \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/ccutil \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/classify \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/cube \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/cutil \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/dict \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/opencl \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/neural_networks/runtime \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/textord \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/viewer \
  $(TESSERACT_PATH)/wordrec \
  $(LEPTONICA_PATH)/src \
  $(TESSERACT_LOCAL)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblept

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#opencv
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_PACKAGE_DIR:= /Users/danielsierraf/Documents/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := off
include $(OPENCV_PACKAGE_DIR)/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := run_detection
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := text_detect.cpp android.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -landroid -llog -ldl
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libtess liblept

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latest setup is failing in a weird way, ndk-build should at least try to compile your module. Maybe there is a bug in `all-subdir-makefiles` when there are ndk modules defined before it, and it doesn't find your module's Android.mk. You can try having only `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)` inside your top level Android.mk.

Anyway, I think you should go back to your first setup, with your module directly in the jni root folder. Then, your main issue is the proper declaration of includes paths. tess-two/jni doesn't contain any headers ? They're in `tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_*_android/src/*`. That means you need to list these in your module declarations, by giving all the absolute paths to `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` variables (like from the original Makefiles: https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/Android.mk#L33)

You also need to add the dependency on liblept for libtess: `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblept` inside libtess library declaration.

If it still fails, there is also another possibility: instead of redefining libtess and liblept modules using the generated .so files, you can directly include `tess-two/jni/Android.mk` and use the same Application.mk than tess-two (copy `tess-two/jni/Application.mk). It will already properly define libtess and liblept modules.

Comment: what version of the NDK are you using ? on which OS ? is the output still really the same, with the missing header ? It's weird that it's still not working... maybe you can check for non-ascii characters, tabs and spaces inside libtess module declaration (quite a desperate check I know).

Comment: It wasn't the exact same output, I have updated my question with my solution. Thank you very much for your help @ph0b